# get check box value with javascript and add those values in a div as i select more than one value

Tags: php, javascript, html

get check box value with javascript and add those values in a div as i select more than one value.

i want something like this: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/4503/w3i.jpg

when items are slected: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8761/fizo.jpg

and than onclick compare btn send all item selected to compare.php page

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    //do not getting what to do? 
</SCRIPT>
<FORM>
         <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="road" VALUE="Car">car
         <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="road" VALUE="bike" CHECKED>bike
         <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="road" VALUE="truck">truck
         <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="road" VALUE="bus" CHECKED>bus
         <div id="compare" style="border:2px solid red;"></div>
      </FORM>
```

Comment: Your tags should be written in lowercase to follow the W3C best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started:

## HTML

```
<form id='compareForm' action='#'>
    <input type='checkbox' name="road" value="car">car
    <input type='checkbox' name="road" value="bike" checked>bike
    <input type='checkbox' name="road" value="truck">truck
    <input type='checkbox' name="road" value="bus" checked>bus
    <button type='submit'>Compare</button>
</form>
<div id="compare"></div>
```

Note that for accessibility and usability, you may want to wrap those words in `label` elements.

## JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('compareForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    var items = document.getElementsByName('road'),
        i;

    // Prevent default form submission functionality
    e.preventDefault();

    // Clears the results box
    document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through all the checkboxes
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        if (items[i].checked) {
            // Do something if the box is checked.
            document.getElementById('compare').innerHTML += '<p>' + items[i].value + '</p>';
        }
    }
});
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dK7T/).

Comment: thanks so far but i want to add item in div as soon as we check checkbox and than send those values to compare.php page @rink.attendant.6

Comment: You would change the event listener target on the change event of the input elements rather than the form submission event then. If you're sending data to a server, AJAX would be required to do it without a page reload. You may want to look into using a framework (personally I recommend jQuery).

Comment: mate your code is working in  jsFiddle and codepen but not on browser     @rink.attendant.6

Comment: Did you put the JavaScript into a `<script>` element on your page?